# How to request vendor-encapsulated-options in dhcpcd.conf on Debian 10 and above

Tags: linux, debian, dhcpcd

I am trying to request vendor-encapsulated-options in /etc/dhcpcd.conf but seems like its not working.

I have the following config

options vendor-class-identifier "HELLO" options vendor-encapsulated-options "HELLO"

restart dhcpcd

systemctl restart dhcpcd

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.